# Custom Facebook Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have been searching for days and reading over facebook docs but I cannot find info on how I can create a custom verb like button.

If you view this website http://www.thekisontheway.com/ you can see their custom like button 'Me gusta' next to the twitter button etc.

Can someone please point me to a the right place on facebook with instructions etc on how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regular like button in spanish...

Here's what Facebook [has to say](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) about it:

> **How do I display the Like button in different languages?**
>
> If you are using the XFBML version include the language code when you
>   instantiate the library. Replace ‘en_US’ in this line with the correct
>   locale code:
>
> ```
> '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
> ```
>
> If you are using the Iframe version include a locale parameter with
>   the proper country code in the src URL. Example:
>
> ```
> src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=fr_FR&..."
> ```
>
> You may need to adjust the width of the Like button to accommodate
>   different languages.